# Ruby on Rails: How to implement this particular model (with inheritance, N-to-M relationship, etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've already defined the data model for my application, which will contain this particular part: [image]

Now, my particular issues are related to modelling "Value" and it's child models "Value_Decimal" and "Value_Text". Basically I wan't to have this hierarchy as it's expected to have several other value types, and each value model with have several other different columns (I'm not considering Single Table Inheritance due to this fact).
How can I implement this with Rails' Active Record, can someone point some directions?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This is highly reminiscent of reddit database schema.

Answer (score 1):

The `item_property_value` table should have a `value_type` column allowing for polymorphic associations.  Then you can create different tables named for each of your various 'value' models inheriting from an abstract `value` model (that has no table).  This way you can avoid STI, but still inherit from one base model.

Because the `item_property_value` model is combining 3 different relationships it will need to be treated as a first-class Rails model which means it will also need an `id` as a primary key.  You can then use a [has-many-through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) mapping to access the actual objects it is joining.

Read up here on [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).  Abstract classes are simply flagged as such:

```
class Value < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

Comment: Hi PinnyM, thanks for replying. Do you suggest any tutorial that covers this? Other point is: how to handle the ternary item-propery-value association?

Comment: Updated.  Regarding tutorials, I suggest reading through the linked association documentation, as well as [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many) and [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) railscast.  In general, railscasts are a great resource for learning about rails.